# Where is where is microsoft.office.tools.word.factory?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ms-word, vsto

I'm in VS2010, in a new Word Add-In project. This is my first attempt at Word development using VSTO. The example I'm trying has this line:

```
Document vstoDoc = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(this.Application.ActiveDocument);
```

But when I add this line Visual Studio says it can't find "Factory". Indeed, it's not in Intellisense.

I've got references to:

> Accessibility
>
> Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word
>
> Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common.v9.0
>
> Microsoft.Office.Tools.v9.0
>
> Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.v9.0
>
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.v9.0
>
> Office

and all the usual System references.

Where am I going wrong and why can't I get to "Factory"?
stdole

Answer (score 0):

That example looks a bit weird to me. Never seen that sort of reference before.

Generally, with Vsto, you hook into EVENTS on, say, the main Word App object.

Then, from within the event, you usually are passed a reference to the particular DOC object that the event is occurring for (say, being opened or saved, etc). In that way, there shouldn't be any need for using the "globals" object or the "factory" object, whereever they might be.

What method is that code in? A little more context might help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the recommended way of doing this is:

```
Globals.ThisAddin.Application.ActiveDocument
```